# Was this photo taken on Friday 29th of May 2020, when the President was moved to a White House bunker

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

This tweet (with over 8,000 shares) was posted recently, implying that the photo of the White House, was taken when the President was evacuated to a bunker.

> [image]
>
> Lights out at #WhiteHouse is a powerful symbol. Total lack of leadership from 
>   @realDonaldTrump
>    #BunkerTrump

— https://twitter.com/iplayitofflegit/status/1267333440438857728

Was this photo taken during the evacuation?

Comment: The tweet implies nothing of the sort.

Comment: Where is the "notable claim"? It's just a photo and bunch of semi-literate comments.

Comment: A white image with the text "blah" shared 800 million times would still not be a claim. Somehow you want to get from a hashtag "#BunkerTrump" to "taken during the evacuation". That seems to be _your_ claim, not the author of the tweet.

Comment: @pipe I didn’t say that a white image with a caption of “blah” shared 800 million times was a claim, so thanks for the strawman. I believe a photo of the White House with the lights out with a comment about trump being in the bunker is a strong implication that the photo was taken while Trump was in the bunker. You’re welcome to disagree, but the comments are getting off topic. Please vote to close, downvote it and move on.

Answer (score 7):

No.

That's a stock image. I can't find the original but did find an article on [NewsThump from 2017](https://newsthump.com/2017/10/30/donald-trump-turns-off-white-house-lights-to-fool-fbi-agents-into-thinking-no-one-is-home/) that seems to be using the same image.

[image]

Comment: https://apnews.com/afs:Content:8983690810 May help but is sparse on details

Comment: Google seems to point to Getty Images, yet I can't find that one there. But the satire article does seem to use the same image, right down to the car on the right. maybe someone can use this to write a better answer?